# Partial Classes and double-click on control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, partial

If I have a function in a partial class (let's say I have 'Button 2' click handler) and then double-click on 'Button 2' in the Form designer, Intellisense (or whatever is in charge now) always throws me to the 'Form1.cs module' (at an ill-defined or blank line), not the new partial class module 'Button2.cs'.  Double-clicking on 'Button1' does the 'correct' action.

For example:

In 'Form1.cs':

```
namespace test01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button 1 pressed");
        }

    }
}
```

In 'Button2.cs' (a public partial class):

```
namespace test01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button 2 pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

This is something I've seen in VS2008 and now in VS2010 and there is no obvious way (to me) to resolve it.

Any help out there?

Comment: No, I agree, if you split code, it doesnt auto find it, however, if you delete the erroneous one from your original form.cs file, it will pick up the correct one in the other file as expected, its just not parsing it for the look ups.

Comment: What is the reason why you are making a new partial class for the same form? The only time I've found it necessary to make a second partial class is when using a ORM and needing to extend auto generated classes. Since both parts of this are "view" parts of the application separating the event handlers doesn't really seem to be necessary as they share the same "concern" (as opposed to separation of concerns).

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are designing the *form*, not the button.  The designer expects that (by convention) all of your event handlers for the controls on the form are located in the form's source code, not the button's source code.  This makes sense when you consider that (generally) button2.cs probably should define a *class* called `button2`, not an instance of the class `Button` whose Name property happens to be "Button2".

EDIT:

Partial classes are designed for a very specific purpose- when a class is generated by a designer or other code generator, it is typically unsafe for a developer to edit that class by hand (because the code generator will come by later and overwrite the file, including the developer's hand-written parts).  Partial classes allow a class to be split across two files- one is generated (by the designer in this case) and one is meant for hand-written code.  Because the class is defined as "partial", the compiler knows that other parts of the class may be defined in other files.

For a project that has several different areas of functionality like you describe, I'd organize those into classes that were unrelated to the UI (so that the functionality can be independently unit tested), and then call them from UI classes as needed.  You should look into concepts like the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or [Model-View-ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) design patterns for an idea of how this works.

A folder structure like this wouldn't be unreasonable as a starting point:

```
Root
|-GUI           // Contains folders related to GUI elements
| |-Forms       // Contains your forms
| |-Controls    // Contains any custom controls
|-Common        // Contains folders for common functionality
| |-IO          // Contains classes relating to I/O
| |-Diagnostics // Contains classes relating to diagnostics
|-Logic         // Contains classes folders to specific business use cases
  |-UseCase1    // Contains classes folders to use case #1 (use a better name, obviously)
  |-UseCase2    // Contains classes folders to use case #2
```

Comment: Thank you, but as usual, it leads to a few more questions.

Comment: Thank you, but as usual, it leads to more questions.  The buttons were just an example to show what I perceived as a problem; perhaps I am missing how I should be using a 'partial classes'.  Note that I am a (very!) old school programmer so objects, classes, constructs and the such don't come easily to me. Second, and probably far beyond the scope of this thread, could you outline (briefly) how I should organize a project that has Windows Forms, five or six tabs, each tab with their own 'class' of functions (I/O, Diagnostics, data input, etc).  Should each tab have it's own class functions?

Comment: @user1408942 Awesome should mean you accept this post as the answer and maybe vote it up if you feel it was helpful.  See the controls to the left of the answer.